# The citation for book or inccollection or inproceding

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

Can some one help me in this cite:

> H. Niederreiter, Random number generation and quasi-Monte Carlo
>   methods, SIAM CBMS-NSF Regional Conference Series in Applied
>   Mathematics, vol. 63, SIAM, Philadelphia, PA, 1992.

I wrote it bibtex as :

```
@book{niederreiter1992random,
  title={Random number generation and quasi-Monte Carlo methods},
  author={Niederreiter, Harald},
  volume={63},
  year={1992},
  journal={SIAM},
  volume={63},
  publisher={Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
  address ={Philadelphia,~US}
}
```

But it looks not correct as the above citation. Please can some one help me?
I am using Chicago style.\bibliographystyle{chicago}

Comment: We would need to know what bibliography style you are using. Please show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) of your document.

Comment: I have used chicago style. \bibliographystyle{chicago}

Comment: How do your citations look? Are they authoryear (Niederreiter, 1992) or numeric [1], or something else? `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` is usually authoryear and does not support Chicago note style, so the date will always be placed after the author and not at the end of the bibliography entry like you want. The bibliography will also be sorted alphabetically by family name which doesn't look like what you want either. It seems that `\bibliographystye{chicago}` is not a good fit for you.

Comment: And do you need it *exactly* like your example, or just approximately? Are there any italics anywhere?

Comment: At least I wold change this: • Remove the `journal` field. • Use `publisher = {SIAM}`. • Use `series = {SIAM CBMS-NSF Regional Conference Series in Applied Mathematics}`. `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` gives the closest to what you want from the standard styles.